# Facebook iPhone app colors

Tags: iphone, facebook, colors

where can I find the colors (and their RGB values) of different pages in the Facebook iPhone app? For example, one the launcher page, the color is some kind of blue, what exactly is its RGB combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Straight from Facebook's iOS SDK:

```
static CGFloat kFacebookBlue[4] = {0.42578125, 0.515625, 0.703125, 1.0};
static CGFloat kBorderGray[4] = {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8};
static CGFloat kBorderBlack[4] = {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1};
static CGFloat kBorderBlue[4] = {0.23, 0.35, 0.6, 1.0};
```

PS: Colour Space is RGBA so these are % of R,G,B,A

Cheers,
Rog

Comment: Hey Rog, thanks for share this. The color above is only for the header. Facebook iPhone App uses several different blue colors.

Comment: Hey Tom best way to go then would be to take a screenshot and use a colour picker to get the colours - I've edited my answer to include one for you straight from my iPhone4. To get the colours have a look at xScope which is a great little App for OSX - http://iconfactory.com/software/xscope

Answer (score 1):

Open in firefox - use the colorpicker add-on :)

From here : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/271/

(or if you're not a firefox fan, take a screenshot and use photoshop / image editor of choice)

Comment: oops - didn't read the app bit in your question, read it as mobile page. It's probably the same blue though . . . Probably better doing it via a screenshot though XCode.

Comment: Hey Dean, can you please explain in more detail on how to do it via screenshot thru XCode?

Comment: Run the facebook app on your iPhone. In the Organiser window in XCode click on your device from the list on the left hand side and choose the screenshots tab. This lets you take screenshots of whatever is on your device's display at the moment. You can drag screenshots you have taken onto your desktop to save for later / open in an image editor etc.